Lebesgue integral of $L^1$ function is differentiable
Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, and define the function
$$
F(x)=\int_a^xf(t)dt.
$$
I want to prove that $F$ is almost everywhere differentiable and that $F'(x)=f(x)$ where $F$ is differentiable.
I am following this text.
First one suppose that $F$ is bounded. The author says to define
$$
g_n(x)=\frac{F(x+1/n)-F(x)}{1/n},
$$
and that $\lim_{n\to\infty}g_n(x)=F'(x)$ for almost every $x$.
I'm ok that IF THE LIMIT EXISTS, its value is $F'(x)$.
QUESTION : How do I prove that the limit exists for almost every $x$ ?
This question is related to this one, but here I am asking for a proof.

Immediate application of Lebesgue's Differentiation Theorem. See Rudin's RCA.


You only need that $F'(x)$ is extant almost everywhere; in that text, this immediately follows from theorem 1.1 alongside the fact that $F$ is absolutely continuous (this is asserted right before thm 1.1).

For any $x$, once $F'(x)$ is known to exist, that $\lim_{n \to \infty} g_n(x) = F'(x)$ follows immediately from the definition of the derivative.


